# How to configure CGMiner with CPU?

Tags: linux, cpu, cgminer

I'd like to start mining Bitcoins on a CPU for testing purposes. I've downloaded CGMiner, compiled it and created a config file without any problems, however starting it results in an error message:

> All devices disabled, cannot mine!

What do I need to do in order for CGMiner to consider my CPU a device?

Comment: You could try an older release of cgminer. Mining bitcoin by CPU is a waste of energy literally.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When building the source use:

```
./configure --enable-cpumining && make
```

At the end of the configure stage you will see a list of what has been enabled, like this:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
cgminer 2.9.6
------------------------------------------------------------------------


Configuration Options Summary:

  curses.TUI...........: FOUND: -lncurses
  OpenCL...............: NOT FOUND. GPU mining support DISABLED
  scrypt...............: Disabled (needs OpenCL)
  ADL..................: SDK NOT found, GPU monitoring support DISABLED

  BitForce.FPGAs.......: Disabled
  Icarus.FPGAs.........: Disabled
  ModMiner.FPGAs.......: Disabled
  Ztex.FPGAs...........: Disabled

  CPU Mining...........: Enabled
  ASM.(for CPU mining).: true

Compilation............: make (or gmake)
  CPPFLAGS.............: 
  CFLAGS...............: -g -O2
  LDFLAGS..............:  -lpthread 
  LDADD................:  -lcurl   compat/jansson/libjansson.a -lpthread     -lm  

Installation...........: make install (as root if needed, with 'su' or 'sudo')
  prefix...............: /usr/local
```

You can get a list of supported options with ./configure --help (standard behavior for configure)

Comment: Thanks! One more question though: where can I find such information? The README isn't very helpful.

Comment: This no longer seems to work in 3.1.1

Comment: BFGMiner still supports CPU mining, FWIW.

Comment: @Luke-Jr Even with the new getblocktemplate protocol?

Comment: Sure, hardware is mostly abstract from protocol, especially in that direction.

Answer (score 16):

CPU mining is no longer supported. See CGMiner FAQ:

> Q: What happened to CPU mining?
>
> A: Being increasingly irrelevant for most users, and a maintenance issue, it is
> no longer under active development and will not be supported. No binary builds
> supporting CPU mining will be released. Virtually all remaining users of CPU
> mining are as back ends for illegal botnets. The main reason cgminer is being
> inappopriately tagged as a virus by antivirus software is due to the trojans
> packaging a CPU mining capable version of it. There is no longer ANY CPU mining
> code in cgminer. If you are mining bitcoin with CPU today, you are spending
> 1000x more in electricity costs than you are earning in bitcoin.