# Bitcoin mining with a Raspberry Pi

Tags: mining-pools, miner-configuration, raspberry-pi

I'm a newbie with this argument. If I want to mine Bitcoin with Raspberry, how should I proceed? In specific:

1. Distro
2. Mining's software

And, How many Bitcoins I can to mine in a month?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll attain about 0.1MH/s with an overclocked and overvolted Raspberry Pi. 963437 years on average to generate a block, or averaged to 0.00000007 BTC a day when using a pool. Not enough to cover the 5W power draw.

Answer (score 0):

The Pi is a very slow computer. You will expend a lot of effort for very little reward. You would generally run [Raspbian](http://www.raspbian.org/).

Then, you would install [CGMiner](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9694/how-to-configure-cgminer-with-cpu). But as I said, it will be mostly a learning experience, rather than a means of profit.